# as3 MouseDown Timer

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to know a way can detect on how long the mouse id down on the item, and like a checker, to check on long the mouse id been down on the specific item. is it possible to  using timer?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but you don't need a timer:

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;

var startTime:int = 0;
var endTime:int = 0;

function SomeFunctionOrClassConstructor():void
{
    item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMouseDown, false, 0, true);
}

function startMouseDown($evt:MouseEvent):void {
    startTime = getTimer();
    item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMouseDown);
    item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endMouseDown, false, 0, true);
}

function endMouseDown($evt:MouseEvent):void {
    endTime = getTimer();
    item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMouseDown, false, 0, true);
    item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endMouseDown);
    trace(endTime - startTime);
}
```

That should get you started.